# Book in which a fake shaman accidentally summons an ifrit

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a book with a female character with unusually dark eyes and hair in a desert setting.

The girl also an orphan, and she can speak any language she'd ever heard (Arabic, Turkish and French mentioned). She remembers from her early childhood her native language, but no one she ever asked about it can identify it, and she doesn't know the name of the language herself.

She lives in the slums and uses her medical diagnostic skills to cure people, but passes it off as magic in which she herself doesn't believe. The reason for her act that it is illegal, or at least frowned upon for women to be healers. In one of her magic sessions with a 'possessed' girl, she decides to use her native language, to impress her clients by making the incarnation more mysterious, but accidentally summons an ifrit or a djinn.

The MC's name starts with an N, no family name.

I heard about the book in YouTube book recommendations now I can't find.

Comment: A very nice description. Well done for adding lots of unique details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [*The City of Brass*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062678108) by S. A Chakraborty.

> The City of Brass is a powerful #ownvoices debut novel people. S.A.
>   Chakraborty’s debut novel follows the story of **Nahri**. She is an
>   **orphaned con artist** living in eighteenth-century Cairo. She doesn’t
>   know who she is, who her parents are, or how she is able to heal
>   people. **She also can understand and respond to seemingly any language**
>   without prior knowledge of the said language including a strange
>   tongue she somehow knows even though she’s never heard anyone else
>   speak it. Nahri is a 20 something young woman with no hope and does
>   tons of swindling activities in order to survive. She has dreams of
>   one day going to Istanbul to learn to heal properly. While executing a
>   **phony healing** ceremony, she **accidentally calls on Dara, a powerful
>   djinn** with a violent past and reveals that Nahri is part djinn,
>   descended from a long line of healers. To be safe she must flee Cairo
>   as she is a target for ifrit (evil djinn with no souls who are her
>   family’s enemies). We then follow her and Dara as they make their way
>   to Daevebad where only those with djinn blood can enter.  Daevabad is
>   far from perfect the rulers oppress the shafit (half-djinn) and there
>   is always the threat of rebellion and war. Nahri is actually part of
>   the tribe that conflicted with the current ruling tribe. She swapped
>   the oppressive powers of France and the Ottoman Empire in her native
>   Egypt for a new set of injustices and oppression.

[image]

Comment: that's the one! Thanks.

Comment: This sounds very interesting.